# How to replace dot separator with comma(for decimals) and comma separator with dot(for group) in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

If I have the string "1,234,567.89" and I want to get "1.234.567,89", what is the easiest way to do this in c#?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I've thought about separating the decimal part, then doing replace for the dots, then adding the decimal back with a dot. But that seems sloppy. That's why I've asked for ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CultureInfo.NumberFormat` for the purpose.

```
var str = "1,234,567.89";
var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator  = ".";
ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = new[]{3};
var result = decimal.Parse(str).ToString("N",ci);
```

Answer (score 1):

easiest way using dummy char `&`

```
var newValue = dd.Replace('.', '&')
                 .Replace(',', '.')
                 .Replace('&', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [string replace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8)

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string myString = "1,234,567.89";
                string replaced = myString.Replace(".", "+").Replace(",",".").Replace("+",",");
                string replacedBack = myString; //viceversa ?? -> re-use memory :P
                Console.WriteLine(replaced);
                Console.Read();
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea if you can explain where do you want to use it. If it is about the number representations in different regions (Example is that we use . as decimal in UK but Denmark uses , for the very same purpose) then you use `CultureInfo` to do the conversions. If we take your example

```
string source = "1,234,567.89";
// convert it to a number format, let us say double
double f = double.Parse(source);
string output = f.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK")); // For Denmark Locale
// n2 is for 2 decimal places
```

The value in `output` is now `1.234.567,89`. That way you can retain different number representations and you can still use them in calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to implement Globalization section into web.config file as follows:

```
<system.web>
     <globalization uiCulture="es-MX" culture="es-MX" />
     ...
</system.web>
```

for this case it uses spanish languaje and MX as country culture, you may change it to "es-ES" for spanish - Spain

If you need to use another culture you may google it, one resource is: 
https://lonewolfonline.net/list-net-culture-country-codes/